Nvidia P102-100 10GB Mining GPU - Ubuntu 24.04
I'm considering purchasing a Nvidia P102-100 10GB Mining GPU to do AI processing stuff. Probably a long shot, but does anyone know if this device will work with Ubuntu 24.04.
From what I can tell, the answer is yes, that it will work, but I don't trust my research.
I want to be able to produce 3 to 4 minutes of text-to-speech in less than 24 hours. I'm using tortoise-tts and an old macbook pro and it does the job, but i just did 2 minutes and it took over 24 hours. So if I could do that in like 10 hours, I'd be happy. I'd like to spend less than $100

Hey Halfstop, welcome to Hardware Recs. How did you decide on the P102? Pascal is pretty old, and 10 GB of VRAM isn’t a huge amount by current standards.

It's the price, I didn't want to spend a lot of money, and I don't mind waiting for stuff to process.

Gotcha. Could you give us your budget, and precisely what AI workloads you’re running? Maybe there’s something better we can get you.

Yeah my requirements are minimal. I want to be able to produce 3 to 4 minutes of text-to-speech in less than 24 hours. I'm using tortoise-tts and an old macbook pro and it does the job, but i just did 2 minutes and it took over 24 hours. So if I could do that in like 10 hours, I'd be happy. I'd like to spend less than $100.

Cool, makes sense. Can you add that to the body of your question?

Also FWIW: the P102-100 is a bad choice because it has massively limited PCI-e bandwidth.

I don’t know a ton about TorToiSe (nor do there seem to be a ton of benchmarks available), but based on the fact that you were able to run it on an older MacBook Pro, I’m going to assume that you’re probably not memory limited.
As such, we can rule out the need for more exotic server-grade cards (e.g. an older Tesla, such as a K40) and stick to consumer GPUs, which are far more plentiful and therefore cheaper on the used market.
At under $100, your best options are going to be the GTX 1080 and RTX 2060. I’d probably favor the latter since it has superior performance in FP16 workloads due to it having tensor cores, where the GTX 1080 does not, but if you’re going to be running in FP32 the GTX 1080’s superior memory bandwidth and CUDA core count will probably help it win.
Both are currently supported by Nouveau and the official Nvidia Linux drivers.

Aside: if you’re willing to spend more like $150, the Nvidia P40 (GP102-based, same as the GTX 1080 Ti) seems to be going for about that and has far more VRAM, more memory bandwidth, and more CUDA cores.
Alternatively, if you’re in the market for a new MacBook anyways, Apple Silicon actually has quite good inference performance (particularly on a per-watt basis.)

No. There are few compatible Linux drivers for those Nvidia cards.
For the ones you can get, check here:
https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/drivers/unix/

Keep in mind that Nvidia’s official drivers and neither the only nor the most popular option for Nvidia drivers on Linux. Nouveau (included in most Mesa installs) is going to be default.

The P102-100 works for me in 24.04 using either driver 535 or 550. I’ve used this GPU in 22.04, too, but only with driver 535.
